# Populate Table View With Friend Request From parse

Tags: uitableview, parse-platform, pfquery

I have a table in parse called Friend Requests with the columns "from" "to" and "status", i am querying this table to find users that have sent me (current user) a friend request, i am doing this with this code:

```
var friendRequests:NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()

let friendRequestsToUser = PFQuery(className: "FriendRequest")
    friendRequestsToUser.whereKey("to", equalTo: PFUser.currentUser()!)
    friendRequestsToUser.whereKey("status", equalTo: "pending")
    friendRequestsToUser.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock( { (AnyObject objects, NSError error) in
        if error == nil {
            self.friendRequests = NSMutableArray(array: objects!)
            self.friendRequestsTableView.reloadData()
        } else {
            print(error?.localizedDescription)
        }
    })
```

this returns the information fine, in the console it shows that it retuns the two user pointers "from" and "to" with the string "pending". Now i want to populate my table view with the "from" PFUser but i cant get it to work. This is what i have been trying:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("friendRequestCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)

    cell.textLabel?.text = friendRequests[indexPath.row] as? String

    return cell
}
```

which isnt working because somehow i have to get the PFUser from the self.friendRequests "from" object and cast it as a user, i hope this all makes sense. Thanks in advance

Comment: please show the objects that returns from friendRequestsToUser query.

Comment: thanks for trying to help, i found the solution. I had to make a variable and then use it, and include the parse includeKey to my query